# python operator overloading __radd__ and __add__

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I'm currently learning python operator overloading (`__radd__` and `__add__` to be exact) and I have the following code

```
class Commuter1:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __add__(self, other):
        print('add', self.val, other)
        return self.val + other


    def __radd__(self, other):
        print('radd', self.val, other)
        return other + self.val


x = Commuter1(88)
y = Commuter1(99)

print(x + y)
```

I have got the following result

[image]

When used separately, I understand how `__radd__` and `__add__` works. But for the line `x + y`, I'm not sure why both `__radd__` and `__add__` methods are evoked.

Comment: What do you think happens when you do `self.val + other`?

Comment: I think he answers your question already.

Comment: ah, i think i got it. 

Inside `__add__` function, the return statement `return self.val + other` invoke the `__radd__` function. The `other` in `return self.val + other` is passed to `__radd__` as the first argument (i.e. `other` in `return self.val + other` is assigned to the `self` in `def __radd__(self, other)`.  And `self.val` in `return self.val + other` is assigned to the `other` argument in `def __radd__(self, other)`. 

I hope I have got this right

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, Python looks at the types of `x` and `y` to decide whether to call `x.__add__` or `y.__radd__`. Since they're both the same type `Commuter1`, it tries `x.__add__` first.

---

Then, inside your `__add__` method, you do this:

```
return self.val + other
```

So, Python looks at the types of `self.val` and `other` to decide whether to call `self.val.__add__` or `other.__radd__`. Since they're unrelated types `int` and `Commuter1`, it tries `int.__add__` first.

But `int.__add__` returns `NotImplemented` for a type it doesn't know about, so Python falls back to calling `other.__radd__`.

---

Inside your `__radd__` method, you do this:

```
return other + self.val
```

So, Python looks at the types of `other` and `self.val` to decide whether to call `other.__add__` or `self.val.__radd__`. Since they both the same type `int`, it tries `__add__` first.

---

And of course `int.__add__` works on another `int`, so it returns a value for the inner `+` inside your `__radd__`, which you return, which returns a value for the `+` inside `__add__`, which you return, which returns a value for the top-level `+`, which you print.

Comment: @Thor No problem; when you're trying to work out the complicated rules for whether it tries `__add__` or `__radd__` first, and what does and doesn't force a fallback, it can be very easy to lose sight of the simpler parts of what's happening…

Comment: do you mind if I ask, how you learned all this? I want to know if I can take away anything from your learning experience so i can attempt to solve similar problem in the future by myself.

Comment: @Thor I might be a bit late, but looking at the official documentation from Python is a nice starter if you don't know where to search. Other than that, it's mostly experience and reading up on other people doing stuff. For this case, the documentation is found here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html