# combining bitwise inverse with bitwise or

Tags: python, bitwise-operators, operator-keyword, bitwise-or

Given the following class:

```py
import operator
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, bah):
        self.bah = bah      

    def __invert__(self):
        return {'not': self.bah}

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.bah

    def __or__(self, other):
        return {'or': [self.bah, other]}    


x = Foo('obj1')
y = Foo('obj2')
```

I can do:

```py
operator.inv(x) # ~x
```

which gives me:

```py
{'not': 'obj1'}
```

I can do:

```py
operator.or_(x, ~y) # x | ~y
```

which gives me:

```py
{'or': ['obj1', {'not': 'obj2'}]}
```

But why I cannot do:

```py
operator.or_(~x, y) # ~x | y
```

which throws the following error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-175-92fdd35dc3b3> in <module>
----> 1 operator.or_(~x, y)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'dict' and 'Foo'
```

And how would I be able to output the following?

```py
{'or': [{'not': 'obj1'}, 'obj2']}
```

Comment: Your operators should be returning instances of `Foo`, so that you can invoke further operators on them.

Comment: The `or` operator evaluates its operands from the left. `~x` is evaluated first and then the `or` is applied. Since the `~x` returns a `dict` from your definition in the `Foo` class, the `or` will be applied to a `dict` and a `Foo` which is undefined. Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#or

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to overload `__ror__` in this case. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51298551/python-operator-overloading-radd-and-add) for details on how Python evaluates operators.

Basically, this statement

```
operator.__or__(~x, y)
```

is the same as

```
x.__invert__().__or__(y)
```

Since `__or__` is not defined for `dict` objects returned by `x.__invert__()`, the call fails. Defining `__ror__` would make the Python interpreter try to evaluate

```
y.__ror__(x.__invert__())
```

for `~x | y` after the first attempt fails.

Comment: Thanks! This is great! `__ror__` as reverse OR. This outputs `{'or': ['obj2', {'not': 'obj1'}]}` which is fine

Comment: Hmm and what about `operator.__or__(~x, ~y)`? I will think about this one as well. But it gives me `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'dict' and 'dict'`

Comment: Well, if that needs to be supported then `__or__` and `__ror__` should not return `dict` objects. They should return `Foo` objects or other objects which support the or operation.

Comment: You are right. Will try to figure out to get `{'or': [{'not': 'obj1'}, {'not':'obj2'}]}` also working

Comment: See also for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892616/python-multiplication-override/6892635#6892635

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `operator.or_()` call looks for the `__or__` method defined in the **first** argument that you give. That's why in the `operator.or_(x, ~y)` case it works fine - `x` is the Foo object that contains the `__or__`. definition.

In the second, `operator.or_(~x, y)`, case, however, the output of `~x` is a dictionary `{'not': 'obj1'}` which does not contain the `__or__` definition.

Answer (score 0):

To provide another answer based on the comments that I should be return instances of `Foo`

```py
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name      

    def __invert__(self):
        return Foo({'not': self.name})

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.name)

    def __or__(self, other):
        return Foo({'or': [self.name, other]})

    def __and__(self, other):
        return Foo({'and': [self.name, other]})   


x = Foo('obj1')
y = Foo('obj2')
```

With this I can do:

```py
>>> operator.or_(~x, y) # ~x | y
{'or': [{'not': 'obj1'}, 'obj2']}
```

And even

```py
>>> operator.or_(~x, ~y) # ~x | ~y
{'or': [{'not': 'obj1'}, {'not': 'obj2'}]}
```