# How do I add/modify methods to built-in objects?

Tags: python, oop, built-in

I made a custom mathematical object (Fractions) that can use some operators (for ex. '+' thanks to`__add__()`)

This means my Fraction can work with ints:

`Fraction(1/2) + 0.5 == 1 # True`

I would like ints and floats to work with my object as well.
for example:

`0.5 + Fraction(1/2) == 1 # Error, not supported...`

How do I make my object work with built-in objects?

Comment: Implement `__radd__`

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51298551/python-operator-overloading-radd-and-add

Comment: Btw there is already a [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) module that supports commutative addition.

Comment: Side-note: `Fraction(1/2)` is passing `0.5` to the `Fraction` constructor. You can't actually implement sane fractions that accept a `float` as their constructor due to precision loss. You almost certainly want `Fraction(1, 2)`.

Comment: Thanks @DeepSpace. Good to know @HTF, but I'm doing it for fun anyway lol. 

@ShadowRanger I'm aware. floats are optional and not recommended in my case(I can pass`Fraction(1, 2)`), they are there just for comfort.